# Extraer una variable dentro de una función javascript

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox

Tengo un checkbox que guarda objetos, tipo carro de compras, pero necesito ayuda para poder reutilizar cualquiera de esos objeto y validarlos en otra función para saber si ese objeto tiene descuento o no. Espero haber sido claro:

```js
/ funcion valida checkbox filiacion
var selections = {};
var checkboxElems = document.querySelectorAll(
  "input[type='checkbox']"
);
var seatsElem = document.getElementById("selected-seats");

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxElems.length; i++) {
  checkboxElems[i].addEventListener("click", displayCheck);
}
function displayCheck(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    selections[e.target.id] = {
      name: e.target.name,
      value: e.target.value,
    };
  } else {
    delete selections[e.target.id];
  }
  var result = [];
  for (var key in selections) {
    var listItem = selections[key].name;
    result.push(listItem);
  }
  seatsElem.innerHTML = result.join("");
}
```

Comment: No estimado para nada claro, favor explicar bien el problema y lo que intentas hacer

Comment: By CHAT GPT: Si deseas acceder a la variable desde fuera de la función, puedes declarar la variable selections fuera de la función, en el ámbito global del archivo JavaScript. De esta manera, la variable se puede acceder desde cualquier otra función en el mismo archivo.

Por ejemplo, si deseas acceder a la variable selections desde otra función en el mismo archivo JavaScript, puedes declarar la variable fuera de la función displayCheck: